# How to resolve "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token" error?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, destructor

I guess this question has already been asked several times, but it seems much dependent on the user case.

I have class in my header file which is being inherited from another class from another package that is:

```
class xyz : public abc {
private:
   string s;
public:
   ros::Publisher eRead;
   xyz(int , const char*);
   ~xyz();
}
```

Now I have my cpp file where I wanna have my definitions:

```
xyz::xyz(int a, const char *b = NULL):abc(a, b){}
xyz::~xyz(){}
```

however, it keeps throwing me the above error.

```
 error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Excuse me, if it is already answered.

Comment: You already implemented the constructor in the header, and you didn't give `a` and `b` types in the cpp file.

Comment: @JamesRoot Edited, but now getting new errors  `undefined reference to `vtable for xyz' `

Answer (score 0):

Ok resolved. 
My header file->

```
class xyz : public abc {
private:
string s;
public:

xyz(int a, const char* b);
}
```

My cpp file:

```
xyz::xyz(int a, const char *b = NULL):abc(a, b){}
```

It was more of my CmakeLists issue and linking directory problem. Thanks anyways.